# how convert bytes to structure in python?

Tags: python, delphi

I have a delphi programm which send record:

```
type 
  TMyNetworkPckg = record
    za: byte;
    zb: char;
    zc: array[0..31] of single;
  end;
```

I receive that data in python. I use udp socks. By default recived data is string. How can i create delphi like record, structure, class, etc. And convert recived data into it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Python library `struct`:

```
import struct
za, zb, zc = struct.unpack('cc32s', data)
```

Comment: Beware of record alignment. This works if it is a `packed record` or the `{$ALIGN OFF}` compiler directive is in effect in Delphi.